# How to turn on keybord LED in Windows

Tags: windows

I have a Mediatech K-010 keyboard with LED. In Linux I could turn on the keyboard LED with this code in terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /tmp/keyboard_light ]; then
xset -led 3 && rm /tmp/keyboard_light
else
xset led 3 && touch /tmp/keyboard_light
fi
```

Since I couldn't run this code in Windows, is there any tricks I could do to turn on the LED? I couldn't find the driver for it and there's no driver shipped with my keyboard.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/151715 . Anyhing else is likely to be proprietary and dependent on the keyboard.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I'm wondering where he's asking for shareware. He's asking how to recognize his keyboard's LED when there is not official driver, maybe he had to ask not for app but generic drivers lol

Comment: @Hannu

I have updated the question to make it clear.